# Scope in link functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
.directive('dateRange', [
    function () {
        return {
            scope:{},
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: 'dateRangeController',
            templateUrl: "daterange.tpl.html",
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var container = element;

                scope.dosmth = function () {
                  ...
                };
            }
        };
    }
]);


 <span ng-click="dosmth()">
```

All I need is to get acces to scope and container inside dosmth() function. I know it is possible. But I cannot understand why in this case that does not work.

Comment: This should be working.. can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: as this is an isolated scope directive you must define the parent scope variables you want to access in your scope definition.Instead of `scope:{}` mention the variables for eg. `scope:{variableorFunctionTobeaccessed:'@'}`

Comment: At this stage I just need an access to 'scope' inside dosmth()

Comment: how are you trying to access `scope`

Comment: Text of `dosmth` function would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In the isolated scope directive you have created ,the scope doesn't have anything inherited from the parent as the declaration is blank `scope:{}`.Declare the variables or functions there as shown below.

```
scope: {
                varOne:'@',
                vartwo:'=',
                methodone:'&'

            }
```

or remove `scope:{}` from your directive definition.

Comment: inside  scope.dosmth() {            ...            }; I just need to get access to 'scope' - not more for now.

Comment: how are you trying to access scope inside `dosmth()`?

Comment: just  typing in debug console  'scope'

Comment: @AngryDev, FYI this method of check will only work when you're paused in debugger inside `dosmth`

Comment: Yes - I did a pause and trying to understand what I have access to